# Problema con Apps Script para enviar correo con archivo adjunto que está guardado en mi Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

Últimamente he empezado con el uso de Apps Script para facilitar algunas tareas, entre ellas el envío de correos a partir de una base a una base de datos realizada en Google Sheets, todo iba bien con mi método `enviarCorreo` sin adjuntar nada en la función sendmail, pero cuando quiero dar el siguiente de paso para adjuntar un archivo único alojado en mi Google Drive, el programa simplemente no funciona, cabe aclarar cuando ejecuto me pide permisos los cuales le he dado al script.

Aquí mi código y descripción.

```
function enviarCorreo(empresa) {

  if (empresa.correo == "")return;

  const plantilla = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('superMensaje');
  plantilla.empresa = empresa;
  const mensaje = plantilla.evaluate().getContent();
  const nombreArchivo = "infovacante.pdf";
  const archivo = DriveApp.getFilesByName('nombreArchivo');

 if(!CV.hasNext())
 {
    console.error("No se puede abrir archivo " +nombreArchivo);
   return;
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: empresa.correo,
    subject: "¡VACANTE IMPERDIBLE, VEN Y TRABAJEMOS JUNTOS!", 
    htmlBody: mensaje,
    attachments: [archivo.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
  });

}
```

Básicamente, el método recibe un parámetro `empresa` que recolecta la información de la hoja de cálculo, seguido un `if` en donde verifica si el atributo correo del Sheet está vacío no enviará ningún correo, después las variables de plantilla con mi mensaje generado en HTML, luego conecto plantilla y empresa para acceder a los métodos desde la plantilla, los siguientes dos renglones es donde establezco el nombre del archivo guardado en mi Google Drive y siguiente a ello uso `DriveApp.getFilesByName()` con el parámetro anterior, hice un `if` para verificar si lee/abre el archivo pdf que se le pide.

Finalmente usé el `MailApp.sendEmail` para poder enviar mi correo con el attachments para enviar mi pdf, notó que la consola me arroja el error de no abrir el archivo como lo escribí.

He intentado lo siguiente:

- Usar `DriveApp.getFileById`, estableciendo el ID del archivo pero también sin funcionar.
- En `attachments` solo he puesto el parámetro `archivo` pero tampoco ha funcionado.
- He creado solo el parámetro `archivo` y luego en attachments y he agregado el ID de la de forma que `attachtments: [archivo.getFileById('El ID de mi archivo')]`.
- El error que arroja el programa si quitó la el `if` que verifica si abre el archivo y en `attachments` solo pongo `[archivo]`es el siguiente:

> Error Exception: Invalid argument: attachments
> enviarCorreo  @ enviarCorreos.gs:21

- Tenía mi documento en una carpeta en drive pero viendo ejemplos preferí sacar el archivo de la carpeta a ver si el error era que al estar en una carpeta el script no busca dentro de ellas para obtenerlo.

Agradecería saber que error estoy cometiendo y como poder enviar un PDF adjunto, obteniendo este último desde mi Google Drive.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so].  El código tiene varios problemas, 1) se declara la variable `mensaje` pero esta no se usa, 2) se asigna una cadena de texto a la variable `nombreArchivo`, pero el código que obtiene el archivo se le pasa la cadena `'nombreArchivo'` en lugar de la variable, la variable CV no ha sido declarada...

Answer (score -2):

A mí me sirvió esta solución: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bl-jPln7R4

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/366204)